# Trying To Convert a Pinescript Function From V4 to V5 But Stumped

Tags: pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4, undeclared-identifier

I am trying to convert what seems like a simple function in V4 to V5 but getting nowhere.  The docs seem relatively vague.  Any ideas?

V4

```
bcwsma(s,l,m) => 
_s = s
_l = l
_m = m
_bcwsma = (_m*_s+(_l-_m)*nz(_bcwsma[1]))/_l
_bcwsma
```

V5

```
bcwsma(s,l,m) => 
_s = s
_l = l
_m = m
_bcwsma = (_m*_s+(_l-_m)*nz(_bcwsma[1]))/_l
_bcwsma
```

The readback in v5 is the infamous undeclared identifier error.

```
line 14: Undeclared identifier '_bcwsma'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 bcwsma(s, l, m) =>
_bcwsma = float(na)
_s = s
_l = l
_m = m
_bcwsma := (_m * _s + (_l - _m) * nz(_bcwsma[1])) / _l
_bcwsma
```